# The origin of "premium" as an adjective

Tags: etymology, word-usage

The original meaning of ***premium*** is a *reward given for some specific act or as an incentive; a prize.* as per its etymology:
***[Premium](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Premium%20)*** (n.) (Etymonline):

> - c. 1600, "reward given for a specific act," from Latin praemium "reward, profit derived from booty,"

The OED cites early adjectival usage examples referring mainly  to petrol especially  in AmE:

***Premium:***

> - (Passing into adj.)  Of a commodity, etc., esp. petrol: superior in quality and therefore commanding a higher price; of a price: such as befits an article of superior quality; higher than usual. orig. U.S.
> - ***1928 National Petroleum News 24 Oct. 115 (Advt.),***  This is our anti-knock gasoline, a premium motor fuel.

While according to Etymonline its first usage was in 1925 referring to butter;

> - ***Adjectival sense of "superior in quality" is first attested 1925, originally in reference to butter.***

Questions;

What's the origin of *premium*  as an adjective? Was butter given as gift/prize, from which the sense of "top quality"? Was its origin from  AmE usage because of its common reference to petrol or was "premium butter" a BrE expression?

Comment: I’d always assumed it was because it was butter for which you’d [be willing to] pay a premium- or for which a premium could be charged.

Comment: Great question. I was also curious about it.

Comment: @Josh61 Per Etymonline, "prime" meaning "first-rate" is from 1620s... http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=prime

Comment: @Josh61 https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=premium+butter%2Cprime+butter&year_start=1750&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpremium%20butter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprime%20butter%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 2):

As usual, it's a metaphor.
***Premium*** in the sense of 'reward given for a specific act' is synonymous with ***prize***.
Both words refer to a Contest frame with multiple entries, judgements, and prizes awarded.
And then the winners get to brag about their prizes (even if they're imaginary).

So *premium butter* is the same construction as *Blue Ribbon Beer* or *New York Times Bestseller* 'The Joy Luck Club'. Essentially the prize/premium name is used as an appositive, and then a modifier, to the following noun, which may be a proper noun.

As to when a noun that modifies another noun becomes an adjective, [the Academy](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/academy.html) decides.

Comment: Thanks, its logical sense and intuitive usage is quite clear as you well describe. My question actually is: why butter, why in 1925?

Comment: Dairy products were delivered house-to-house daily in 1925 in the US, at least, and there was considerable competition in, and advertising for, dairy products, of which butter is the standard-carrier (note the phrase "full cream butter"). And butter is just one example -- but it was the one you found.

Comment: @Josh61 - 1925 would have been about when "name brands" of dairy products first began to be used.  Prior to that it was no-name stuff from the local dairy maid or whatever.  (This likely coincided to a degree with the availability of mechanical refrigeration.)